# Returning a data frame from a subroutine, and replacing an existing data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a subroutine that returns a data frame. The returned data frame is then stored into another (global) data frame like this:

```
resultsDF = stepwise(cDelta)
```

Sometimes, depending on the input criterion, the returned data frame may contain more than one column. At other times, it may just return one column.

The issue is this: Let's say I run this step for the first time, and the **resultsDF** data frame is created with five columns. Now, I may change the input criterion, and re-run the same subroutine. This time, let's say the returned data frame contains only one column. In such cases, the **resultsDF** would still contain (preserve) the four extraneous columns from the previous run.

What I need is that the **resultsDF** data frame be replaced *in its entirety* every time I run the subroutine. It looks like the *update()* function might be helpful here. However, I have other situations where *more than one* data frames are returned from a subroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you clear the variable resultsDF before calling your function (or just before the return statement if you use it in the function) by using resultsDF = None ?

Comment: Oh wow, is it that simple?! Let me try that and I will let you know. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Hope it works:) If not supply some code with which to replicate your problem! I tried to replicate it, but for me it simply worked.